# Training GRU for multivariate data

Tags: keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train multivariate data using GRU.
Data input/output format are
Input shape (1231, 30, 3)
Output shape (1231, 7, 3)

There are altogether 1231 dataset.
Input shape is 30,3 and output shape is 7,3 as shown below.

Input data

```
[[451. 163. 288.]
 [458. 166. 292.]
 [460. 168. 292.]
 [460. 168. 292.]
 [464. 169. 295.]
 [470. 172. 298.]
 [476. 174. 302.]
 [479. 176. 303.]
 [479. 176. 303.]
 [479. 176. 303.]
 [479. 176. 303.]
 [486. 179. 307.]
 [491. 183. 308.]
 [494. 183. 311.]
 [501. 187. 314.]
 [507. 191. 316.]
 [510. 193. 317.]
 [510. 193. 317.]
 [514. 195. 319.]
 [518. 196. 322.]
 [522. 196. 326.]
 [533. 201. 332.]
 [540. 204. 336.]
 [545. 205. 340.]
 [545. 205. 340.]
 [558. 209. 349.]
 [566. 214. 352.]
 [574. 218. 356.]
 [581. 221. 360.]
 [589. 224. 365.]]
```

Output data

```
[[592. 294. 298.]
 [592. 294. 298.]
 [583. 290. 293.]
 [578. 289. 289.]
 [569. 285. 284.]
 [567. 284. 283.]
 [565. 283. 282.]]
```

I have GRU model as below.

```
n_steps = 30
predict_period=7
def create_GRU_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(GRU(32, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features), activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.4)) 
    model.add(GRU(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3)) 
    model.add(Dense(predict_period,n_features)) 
    
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer, loss='mse') 
    return model
GRU_model = create_GRU_model()
```

Error is as follows.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6f82c6f91502> in <module>()
     20     model.compile(optimizer, loss='mse')
     21     return model
---> 22 GRU_model = create_GRU_model()
     23 #stack_lstm_model = load_model('stack_lstm_model')
     24 # fit model

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations.py in get(identifier)
    579     raise TypeError(
    580         'Could not interpret activation function identifier: {}'.format(
--> 581             identifier))

TypeError: Could not interpret activation function identifier: 3
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The [parameters to `Dense` in order are features and activation function. What are you trying to give with `predict_period`?

Comment: So how can I have output in 7x3 shape?

Comment: Use `return_sequences` in all GRU layers and take just the last three outputs. You'll probably be better off using the functional API instead of `Sequential`